# Getting an error when formatting a thumb drive

Tags: terminal, macos

Inside of Terminal.app, I'm trying to format a thumb drive and I'm getting the following "error":

> does not appear to be a whole disk

The line I typed in was the following:

```
sudo diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk1s2 GPT JHFS+ HighSierra R
```

What might I be typing in wrong? Why is it stating this?

Answer (score 4):

You're asking it to partition a whole disk - it wipes existing volumes, and creates the ones you specify.

But, you're giving it /dev/disk1s2, which is itself a partition.

If you're trying to reformat the whole drive, you should be using /dev/disk1

Also, typically, people use eraseDisk to wipe and reformat it -

> diskutil eraseDisk Usage:  diskutil eraseDisk format name
>   [APM[Format]|MBR[Format]|GPT[Format]]
>           MountPoint|DiskIdentifier|DeviceNode (Re)-partition a whole disk (create a new partition map). This completely erases any existing
>   data on the given whole disk; all volumes on this disk will be
>   destroyed. Format is the specific file system name you want to erase
>   it as (HFS+, etc.). Name is the (new) volume name (subject to file
>   system naming restrictions), or can be specified as %noformat% to skip
>   initialization (newfs). You cannot erase the boot disk. Ownership of
>   the affected disk is required. Example: diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+
>   UntitledUFS disk3

Comment: ok yeah. i did a diskutil list and i see it now as disk1. man that was confusing!

Comment: diskX are the actual disks, and diskXsY are the partitions on them.

Comment: @TheAngryYeti As I understand it, the "s" stands for "slice", which is (sort of) another name for partition. Thus, you can think of `diskX` as meaning "disk #X", and `diskXsY` as meaning "the Y'th slice (partition) of disk #X".